# Distance of a point (inside) circle with arbitrary direction

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

For a circle with radius $r$ centered at point $A \equiv (x_a, y_a)$,

How to calculate distance **CM** in, a given arbitrary direction

$d \equiv (d_x, d_y) \leftarrow \|d\|_2 = 1.0 $

for a point 
$C \equiv (C_x, C_y)$ inside the circle and a point on the Circle $M$
(see figure below)

[image: Distance Problem]

Comment: Are you given point $C$ and some angle $\theta$ and need to find $M$?

Comment: I would like to see a answer in terms of radius and angleCMA (say $\theta$). Coincidentally I happen to be working on the same problem in relation to a physics derivation.

Answer (score 0):

The parametric equation of line $CM$ is
$$
(x,y)=(C_x+d_x\,t,C_y+d_y\,t).
$$
Substitute these coordinates into the equation of the circle
$$
(x-x_a)^2+(y-y_a)^2=r^2
$$
to get the values of $t$ giving the intersections. Of course you'll get two solutions for $t$: if you want only the intersection of the circle with the **ray** starting at $C$ with direction $d$, then you must keep only the positive solution.